# Retrieving original values of modified references

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've figured out how to use the `ObjectStateManager` and `ObjectStateEntries` to determine original values of scalar properties for a given entity.

What I need to know now is how to do the same for navigation properties. The `GetModifiedProperties` method on `ObjectStateEntry` doesn't return navigation properties.

Comment: I had to go the internal caching approach outside of the context. I have one issue. Its starts caching immediately after the object is created. So when a query starts building the object graph, it already started caching. Is there a way to find out when an object graph has been completed?

Answer (score 0):

Just get all added or deleted ObjectStateEntries and then use LINQ to only get those that represent relationships:

```
private IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> GetModifiedRelationshipEntries()
{
    return ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
            EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted)
            .Where(e => e.IsRelationship);
}
```

I found these two blog entries by Daniel Simmons very useful when writing audit log for EF:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2008/01/16/ef-extension-method-extravaganza-part-i-objectstateentry.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2008/01/17/ef-extension-methods-extravaganza-part-ii-relationship-entry-irelatedend.aspx